# How to relate ga:campaign and ga:pagePath (content) on Google Analytics Export API?

Tags: java, javascript, google-analytics

Using custom reports you are able to drill down on a specific campaign and then choose the Landing Page or content page that the individual visitor choose.  When I try to retrieve the same information through the `Google Analytics Export API`, I get an error, if I try to relate those two dimensions in my feed.  Is there any success story about getting this information together.  I know this is possible, we just don't know what is the correct combination.

Since I had no progress on this issue during the last week I thought about giving a little more information.  I am presenting below a screen shot of an actual report of the Google Analytics UI giving the information that I am trying to pull and I am getting no info.  Basically the campaing information group by the pagePage landed.  So I am able to know who clicked on my emails and where that person landed.

[image: Landing page from Campaign information]
<sub>(source: [readytocloud.com](http://img.readytocloud.com/ganalytics-stackoverflow/R2C-6-28-2009-002.png))</sub>

I just found other people with the same questions on the [Google Analytic Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=0a70a94663dfb464&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with some Google analytics data. It seems to be picky about what metric you join it to, but ga:pageviews works. Both ga:campaign and ga:pagePath are dimensions and you need to join them to a metric. You can reference GA documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#validCombinations) regarding what are the valid combinations. As an example, I managed to retrieve a really long report using (replace with your profile id):

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:123456&dimensions=ga:campaign,ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=ga:campaign,ga:pagePath&start-date=2009-01-01&end-date=2009-06-30
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am trying to execute your sample with my table id, but I cannot get it to work.  I am getting an Authorization Required.  I am authenticating with Google Analytics before requesting the URI.   Let me know if you know what steps to take before executing the script.  Thanks again.

Comment: You need to authenticate to GA separately by sending an extra header in the http request. See http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html and http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/1.0/gdataProtocol.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `java` or `servlet`, you can use authentication method in analytics API to authenticate first, and then you can retrieve data from the profile of that user.